Download captcha using ADODB Stream in VBA
I am trying to download capthca through adodb stream and here is my code
    Set oCaptcha = .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
    .Wait 500
    
    Debug.Print oCaptcha.Attribute("src")
    Dim http As Object
    Dim imgSrc As String
   imgSrc = oCaptcha.Attribute("src")
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", oCaptcha.Attribute("src"), False
    http.send
    Dim SaveToFile
    Debug.Print http.Status
    If http.Status = 200 Then
        Dim oStream As Object
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.STREAM")
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Open
        oStream.write http.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Number.png", 2
        oStream.Close
        
    End If

The code is working well but the link is not fixed. I mean what is displayed in the website is different from what I downloaded. here is the link if you would like to test and see https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp 
I tried to capture the element itself and it worked on my pc but didn't work well on another pc and return me an empty image. I am using vba and selenium.

Your code works for me. Only the header of the image locks strange. Whats the difference of your two pcs? Do you get the same path? Do you get the same structure of the file?

Yes the same path and same structure (the same file). I know the code is working and downloaded captcha but not what is displayed in the webpage!!

Have you checked different viewers (or browser) for the image? Maybe it is only a viewer issue.

You can take the url of the captcha and paste it and refresh the page and you will get new different image each time. So the captcha is dynamic and I need only what is displayed during the load of the page.. need an idea except saving screenshot of the element

So miss interpreted your question, you want to save the image without sending a new request.

Perfect. Yes that is exactly what I want to do. I can use python or vba.

The captcha will change every time you send a request to the server. Sending a XMLHHTP request or refreshing the page will cause the captcha to be changed every time. This is how captcha is designed for security.

Thanks a lot, Haluk. I need to download the existing captha. I know about security issues.
